# Spring batch how to use ItemReadListener

Tags: spring, error-handling, spring-batch

I use spring batch for processing a file. The configuration of all components is made programatically.

I have a job that contains several TaskletSteps:

```
@Bean
    @Named(SEEC_JOB)
    public Job seecJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get(SEEC_JOB).start(seecMoveToWorkingStep()).next(seecLoadFileStep())
                .on(ExitStatus.COMPLETED.getExitCode()).to(seecFlowMoveToArchiveOk()).from(seecLoadFileStep())
                .on(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode()).to(seecFlowMoveToArchiveKo()).end().build();

    }
```

My question focus on seecLoadFileStep(), the detail bellow:

```
@Bean
    public TaskletStep seecLoadFileStep() {
        TaskletStep build = stepBuilderFactory.get(SEEC_LOAD_FILE_STEP)
                .<SeecMove, SeecMove>chunk(cormoranProperties.seec.batchSize.get()).reader(seecItemReader())
                .writer(seecItemWriter()).build();
        return build;
    }
```

I would like to throw a specific exception if a reading error hapens (by reading error I mean: the file is corrupted for example or it is wrong, absent xml tag...).

I have been reading spring batch doc and I think ItemReadListener is my guy:

```
public interface ItemReadListener<T> extends StepListener {

    void beforeRead();

    void afterRead(T item);

    void onReadError(Exception ex);

}
```

but, I don't know how to use it! I have tried doing my seecItemReader() implements this interface but onReadError method is never called.

I don't know how to declare/register in the taskletStep the ItemReadListener.

Here a bit of spring doc:

> Any class that implements one of the extensions of StepListener (but
>   not that interface itself since it is empty) can be applied to a step
>   via the listeners element. The listeners element is valid inside a
>   step, tasklet or chunk declaration. It is recommended that you declare
>   the listeners at the level which its function applies, or if it is
>   multi-featured (e.g. StepExecutionListener and ItemReadListener) then
>   declare it at the most granular level that it applies (chunk in the
>   example given).
>
> An ItemReader, ItemWriter or ItemProcessor that itself implements one
>   of the StepListener interfaces will be registered automatically with
>   the Step if using the namespace  element, or one of the the
>   *StepFactoryBean factories. This only applies to components directly injected into the Step: if the listener is nested inside another
>   component, it needs to be explicitly registered (as described above).

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/SimpleStepBuilder.html#listener(org.springframework.batch.core.ItemWriteListener)?

Answer (score 3):

As I guessed it was easier than I thougth, for registering programatically the ItemReadListener is via listener method in the tasklet configuration:

```
   @Bean
    public TaskletStep seecLoadFileStep() {
        TaskletStep build = stepBuilderFactory.get(SEEC_LOAD_FILE_STEP)
                .<SeecMove, SeecMove>chunk(cormoranProperties.seec.batchSize.get()).reader(seecItemReader()).listener(seecItemReaderListener())
                .writer(seecItemWriter()).build();
        return build;
    }
```

And now the onError method is called when an Exception happens.